# Irreducibility test in a number field

Tags: number-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

While thinking about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856404/irreducibility-of-higher-order-polynomials-over-mathbbq) question I noticed that if $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x) = x^9 + 3 x^6 + 165 x^3 + 1$ then $$\left(\frac{\alpha^3+1}{3 \alpha}\right)^3 = -6$$ so $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ contains a cube root of $6$. This shows that $3 \mid [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}]$. 
Moreover, $f(x)$ factors over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[3]6)$ as
$$f(x) = (x^3 + 3 \sqrt[3]6\,x + 1)(x^3 + 3 \zeta \sqrt[3]6\,x + 1)(x^3 + 3 \zeta^{-1} \sqrt[3]6\,x + 1)$$
where $\zeta$ is a primitive third root of unity. Is there a "simple" way to use these facts to show that in fact $f(x)$ must be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, e.g. by relating this to some finite field that contains a cube root of $6$?

Comment: Do we really need to go through finite field? I think the factorization you have is very good! I think we can consider the tower of fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{6})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{6},\zeta)$, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\zeta)$

Comment: Great stuff with the factorization. I just noticed that $\alpha=\root3\of2-\root3\of3$ is a zero of your first cubic factor. Looks like the nonic is the minimal polynomial of this difference of cube roots! Need to think whether that leads to a simple irreducibility proof?

Comment: Anyway, looks like $L=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2,\root3\of3,\zeta)$ is the degree 18 splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Basically "all" we need to do is to show that $x^3-3$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$. Then we are done. The usual proof of the existence of a primitive element tells us that $\alpha$ generates $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2,\root3\of3)$. Therefore its minimal polynomial has degree nine.

Comment: In other words, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55515/11619) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/367013/11619) will settle the question. [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csqrt%5B%5C%203%5D%7B3%7D%5Cin%5C%20Q%5Cleft(%5Csqrt%5B%5C%203%5D%7B2%7D%5Cright)%24&p=1) gives more related threads.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Good catch! Turns out that $2\alpha^7+7\alpha^4+311\alpha = -45 \sqrt[3]2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Or a bit nicer $$\frac{\alpha(\alpha^3+7)}{2\alpha^3-1}=\sqrt[3]2.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It suffices to show that $g(x)=x^3 + 3 \sqrt[3]6\,x + 1$ is irreducible over $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]6)$ because
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):K]=3 \implies [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] = 9$$ There are general algorithms to factor polynomials over number fields. However, I present two *ad hoc* ways for this particular polynomial.

---

### First method

If $g$ is reducible, then it has a root in $K$. The only real root of $g$ is $\gamma= -0.182329$, this number is an algebraic unit. Hence $-1/\gamma = 5.48461$ is also an algebraic unit.

> Let $u>1$ be the fundamental unit of a real cubic field with one real embedding, then $$u^3 > \frac{|\delta|-27}{4}$$ where $\delta$ is the discriminant of the field.

An instructive proof is given in *Number Fields* by Daniel Marcus (chapter 5). *Introductory algebraic number theory* by Alaca (chapter 13) contains an excessively verbose proof.

Now apply this proposition to ring of integer of $K$, with $\delta = -972$, we found its fundamental unit is $>6.1819$. Therefore $-1/\gamma \notin K$ so $\gamma \notin K$.

---

### Second method

Replace $x$ by $x/\sqrt[3]6$ in $g(x)$ gives $x^3+18x+6$, irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Denote a real root of $x^3+18x+6$ by $\gamma$. It suffices to show $\gamma \notin K$. Assume $\gamma \in K$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]6) = \mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$. Both $$\{1,\sqrt[3]6, \sqrt[3]6^2\} \qquad \{1,\gamma, \gamma^2\}$$ are basis of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\text{tr}$ denote the trace of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. 
There exists $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$\gamma = a + b\sqrt[3]6+c\sqrt[3]6^2$$
Taking trace both sides gives $$0=\text{tr}(\gamma) = 3a \implies a=0$$
So $$\gamma^2 = b^2\sqrt[3]6^2+c^2\sqrt[3]6^4+12bc$$, taking trace again gives $$\tag{1} -36=\text{tr}(\gamma^2) = 36bc \implies bc=-1$$ Consider $\gamma^3$ gives $$\tag{2}-18=\text{tr}(\gamma^3)=18(b^3+6c^3) \implies b^3+6c^3=-1$$
It is easy to see that $(1),(2)$ have no rational solutions, this contradiction shows $\gamma \notin K$.

Comment: Isn’t $\gamma/b = \sqrt[3]6 -\sqrt[3]6^2/b^2$?

Comment: @WimC  Yes, I corrected it.

Comment: (+1) Second method is one of my favorite argument.

Comment: Nice. Not unlike the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/367013/11619). Those became relevant after I realized that $\root3\of2-\root3\of3$ is a zero of the first cubic in WimC's factorization. All the nine zeros are $\zeta^k\root3\of2-\zeta^\ell\root3\of3$. I don't know whether I should be embarrassed or not about missing this earlier :-)

Answer (score 3):

This answer elaborates on the observations made by @JyrkiLahtonen in the comments. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^9+3x^6+165x^3+1$ then $$\tag1 (\alpha^3+1)^3+6(3\alpha)^3=0$$ and $$\tag2 3(\alpha^3+7)^3+2(\alpha^3-8)^3=0.$$
Equation $(1)$ is already mentioned in the question and $(2)$ was found by observing that $$(1-b)(\alpha^3+a)^3+(a-1)(\alpha^3+b)^3$$ is linear in $\alpha^3$ for any $a,b$ and then picking suitable values.  From this it follows that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ contains both a cube root of $3$ and a cube root of $2$. As mentioned in the comments, this suffices to show that $\alpha$ has degree $9$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Nice that you worked out how to get the individual cube roots with $\alpha$.